# Is it possible to get Google Analytic goal value by date?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

[Google Analytics Management API goals endpoint.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/get) this is the link showing the goal endpoint I will be using to get a value. Is it possible for me to get the goal value broken up by date? I want to know the goal value for each day so I can create a line graph with accurate data. This endpoint is apart of the management API, but I know the core reporting API is more flexible with sorting by date. I would like to know if it is possible. If it is, please enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you can't use the reporting API? You can use dimension=ga:date and metrics=ga:goalXXCompletions (ga:goal1Completions).

See the link to the query explorer report below:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2016-01-01&end-date=2016-03-27&metrics=ga%3Agoal1Completions&dimensions=ga%3Adate&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION&max-results=10000

Answer (score 0):

You can query them together.

```html
# get report data
query.list <- Init(start.date = "XXXXXX",
                   end.date = "XXXXXX",
                   dimensions = "ga:date",
                   metrics = "ga:goalXXValue",
                   table.id = "ga:XXXXX")
```